# Does adding a web page to the home screen of iPad use UIWebView or WKWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, wkwebview

Forgive me this seemingly basic question, but I have searched for a few days and cannot find official documentation stating what actually happens when a web page is launched from a home page link on an iPad.

`JavaScript` Performance tests on `iOS 8.3` (ex: http://www.mobilexweb.com/samples/nitro.html) show no noticeable difference in either Safari or in a pinned app.  **(~900 ms vs 3200 ms on Chrome)**

However, there is a bug in `iOS 9`  (https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/12241) that is breaking our `AngularJS` application, and this bug only manifests in `UIWebView`. We can recreate the bug when the web page is pinned but not within Safari.

*So that means the pinned app is using `UIWebView`, correct?*

Or

*Is `UIWebView` now using the Nitro rendering engine which explains both cases?*

Thanks for your help on finding the official documentation!

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to set which one to use for a pinned web app?

Comment: As far as I know, when saving a web page (that has the meta tags `<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />`) to your home screen, it will open the site with the UIWebView control. I don't know if it is possible to choose which one is used. From my understanding, WKWebView cannot be used without displaying the URL of the site (for security reasons).